# general suggestions on debugging .Internal() in R

Tags: r

i am fighting a nasty bug that have no idea where to start.  this post --

[General suggestions for debugging in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-in-r)

-- has lots of tips and advice about debugging in general.  unfortunately, none of the strategies apply to problems within functions called by `.Internal()`

how do i diagnose a problem that appears to occur within `Internal` functions rather than within normal R functions?

fresh R session:

```
> .Internal(La_rs(matrix(1,1),TRUE))
$values
[1] 1
```

my R session after a long script:

```
> .Internal(La_rs(matrix(1,1),TRUE))
Error: 'a' must be a complex matrix
```

i have [a separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35447971/internalla-rsx-false-crashes-r-after-long-reproducible-script-on-windows) that provides a reproducible example for my specific problem, but wanted to pose the question more generally in a separate thread:

**how do R users troubleshoot functions called within `.Internal()`?**

Comment: gdb using a debug build probably